# Callback is not a function with added if check?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a function that I am trying produce a callback from. I have even put in the `if(cb) { cb(); }` check and that does fix the error, but then the callback function does not run. So I must ask what I am doing wrong here.

I am also using React/Redux so some of this may seem a bit confusing. But here is the code.

if I `console.log(cb)` inside of the `sortOffers` function then it returns undefined.

Original function:

```
export function sortOffers({ currency, name, geolocation, category, btc, sys, zec }, cb) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get('/API/offers/sort', {
        params: { currency, name, geolocation, category, btc, sys, zec },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: SORT_OFFERS, payload: response.data });
        dispatch(reset('sorter'));
      })
      .then(() => cb())
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      });
  };
}
```

function being called:

```
  submitSort(values) {
    this.props.sortOffers(values, () => {
      console.log(10 + 10);
    });
    // this.props.filter(this.props.filterOption);
```

I want to pass the commented out function, however I thought that maybe that was the problem. So I wanted to do a simple console log to see if I could get it to work and I cannot.

Comment: It looks like it should work. What does `console.log(cb)` show?

Comment: Uh, shouldn't it be something like `this.props.sortOffers(values, () => {...})(dispatch);` <- to execute the returned inner function as well. You sure complicated this with all the arrows, callbacks inside promises etc.

Comment: @Barmar it says undefined.

Comment: @adeneo both are actions that have dispatch inside them

Comment: But `sortOffers` *returns* another function, wouldn't you have to execute that if you want something ... anything, to happen ?

Comment: Lets try an example, maybe that's easier -> https://jsfiddle.net/Lersos3k/1/, or ... you could just try adding `()` to your call to `sortOffers`

Comment: See I feel like mine should work with the console.log but it isnt.